# matlab: 2D data binning

Tags: matlab, distribution, histogram, bin

I need some help with calculating cumulative distribution.

lets say I have data like that:

```
data = abs(randn(1000,1));
```

I have to calculate probability cumulative distribution and bin it to reduce amount of points. I am doing it like that (lets take bin = 50):

```
[n, x] = hist(data, 50);
y = cumsum(n);
y = y./max(y);
```

The problem is, that now I have a lot of points close to y=1, but only few close to zero. I'd like to have kind of equal distribution distribution of points (additional binning on y axis?). I hope you know what I mean :) How I can do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it actually means that in your `data` vector many points are close to 0. The usual procedure is to transform the data using log: log2 or log10, depending on the nature of the data.

Try

```
[n, x] = hist(log10(data), 50);
y = cumsum(n);
y = y./max(y);
```

You can also try `sqrt` instead of `log` or other functions.

**UPDATE**

Reviewing the question after your comment I think you want to use something like this:

```
bin = 10.^(linspace(log10(min(data)),log10(max(data)),50));
[n, x] = hist(data, bin);
y = cumsum(n);
y = y./max(y);
plot(bin,y,'.')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but after log10(data) curve is not exponential anymore and x vaules are going below zero... I just need to have the same curve shape but with hmm..less datapoints close to y=1 (and high x). That is why I was thinking about additional binning along y axis...